# HTML forms on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, mobile-safari

I have created a simple HTML form on a Google Site which users can send feedback with. It works fine in IE and chrome browsers, and on my Android phone, but when someone with an iPhone and Safari looks at the page(chrome on iPhone is fine), all they see is white space where the form should be.

I have have been searching around, trying different CSS and think maybe it has something to do with scrolling? Anyone know how I can fix this to work on iPhones?

```
<font color="#173c54" size="3" face="verdana">
<form id="myForm" style="display:block">

<label for="firstNameLabel" id="firstNameLabel">First Name</label><br>
<input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" /><br><br>
<label for="lastNameLabel" id="lastNameLabel">Last Name</label><br>
<input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" /><br><br>
<label for="emailLabel" id="emailLabel">Email</label><br>
<input id="myEmail" name="myEmail" type="text" /><br><br>
<label for="commentLabel" id="commentLabel">Comment</label><br>
<textarea id="comment" name="comment"  rows="5" ></textarea><br><br>
<br>
<input type="reset" value="Submit" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(DataSaved).processForm(this.form)" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

<div id="Message"></div>
</font>
```

Comment: try it with no styling - check if that works. if not, cut it down to just an empty form with a submit button an nothing else... figure out what minimal amount makes it not look that way.. then start adding things back until until a thing breaks it - that's what's causing the problem. tell us what that thing is

Comment: Thanks Taryn. I cut everything out except the input fields and still nothing.

Comment: cut the input fields too. down to just a button... ?

Comment: The code is embedded into the site as an Apps Script, do you think this might be the problem?

Comment: I embedded the code straight into the HTML of the site, and the fields show up, but not the reset button. I may have to figure out how to do it this way instead of embedding the apps script.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem, but as you know, iPhone have retina display. So you might want to add this piece of meta tag:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name='viewport', content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Where? Preferably at header. Either, just put this on topmost of your code.

Comment: Thanks Bentinata. I did try this, and I think now the issue is that I'm using an Apps script to embed the form. I just tried the code straight into the HTML of the site and it's shows up on iPhone. This just means I have to rewite the whole thing to get the scripts working again etc.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem. Instead of inserting the apps script into the Google site page, I inserted a link to the apps script and have open in its own window. It works on both Android and iPhone now.